# Cannot hook any Prestashop module to displayMaintenance

Tags: php, smarty, prestashop-1.7

I wanted to hook the social media follow and some other Prestashop modules to the displayMaintenance hook but it came up with an error:

```
ContextErrorException in Module.php line 2221:
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object
```

According to this [documentation](http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS17/Hooks+in+PrestaShop+1.7.x), this hook displays new elements on the maintenance page.

I also noticed that same error comes up when I tried to use a global variable that contains {$urls} like {$urls.theme_assets}  and {$urls.base_url} inside the maintenance.tpl file to insert a file from the theme directory. It looks like those modules and variables don't work inside the maintenance.tpl file.

Update:
Here is the a part of the code from the maintenance.tpl file containing the hook.

```
div class="maintenance-container">
            <div class="page-header">
                {block name='page_header_logo'}
                    <div class="logo"><img src="{$shop.logo}" alt="logo" width="160"></div>
                {/block}
                {block name='hook_maintenance'}
                    {$HOOK_MAINTENANCE nofilter}
                {/block}

                {block name='page_header'}
                    <h1>{block name='page_title'}{l s='We will be back soon' d='Shop.Theme.Global'}{/block}</h1>
                {/block}
            </div>
            {block name='page_content_container'}
                <section id="content" class="page-content page-maintenance">
                    {block name='page_content'}
                        {$maintenance_text nofilter}
                    {/block}
                </section>
            {/block}
        </div>
```

The following code is used to add a module directly to the position:

```
$this->registerHook('displayMaintenance'));
```

However, I also successfully transplanted modules to this position in the backend. But when you check the frontend, it throws the error.

Comment: Can you add a code which you try to use for maintenance hook?

Comment: I have added some additional information as you requested.